# Different Cases's output at different levels

Tags: functions, pattern-matching

Why do these 2 input return different output when considered at different level `lev`

```
Cases[{{1, 2, 3}, a, {4, 5^a, {a^6}}}, t:{__Integer} :> t, {lev}]  
Cases[{{1, 2, 3}, a, {4, 5^a, {a^6}}}, t__ /; Element[t,Integers] :> t, {lev}]
```

(They give the same output only at level -2 and 1, eg

```
Do[
 Print[ lev, "\n",
  Cases[{{1, 2, 3}, a, {4, 5^a, {a^6}}}, t : {__Integer} :> t, {lev}],
   "\n",
  Cases[{{1, 2, 3}, a, {4, 5^a, {a^6}}}, 
   t__ /; Element[t, Integers] :> t, {lev}], "\n"],
 {lev, -3, 4}]

-3
{}
{}


-2
{{1,2,3}}
{{1,2,3}}


-1
{}
{1,2,3,4,5,6}


0
{}
{}


1
{{1,2,3}}
{{1,2,3}}


2
{}
{1,2,3,4}


3
{}
{5}


4
{}
{6}
```

Comment: `Element` can accept a single expression, as well as a list of expressions, for its first argument, so you need to include single-element pattern in your first code. i.e. you could do: `Cases[{{1, 2, 3}, a, {4, 5^a, {a^6}}}, t : _Integer | {__Integer} :> t, {lev}]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Element` can accept a single expression, as well as a list of expressions, for its first argument, so you need to include single-element pattern in your first code.

That is,

```
Cases[{{1, 2, 3}, a, {4, 5^a, {a^6}}}, t : _Integer | {__Integer} :> t, {lev}]
```

Verfication:

```
Do[Print[lev, "\n", 
  Cases[{{1, 2, 3}, a, {4, 5^a, {a^6}}}, 
   t : _Integer | {__Integer} :> t, {lev}], "\n", 
  Cases[{{1, 2, 3}, a, {4, 5^a, {a^6}}}, 
   t__ /; Element[t, Integers] :> t, {lev}], "\n"], {lev, -3, 4}]

-3
{}
{}


-2
{{1,2,3}}
{{1,2,3}}


-1
{1,2,3,4,5,6}
{1,2,3,4,5,6}


0
{}
{}


1
{{1,2,3}}
{{1,2,3}}


2
{1,2,3,4}
{1,2,3,4}


3
{5}
{5}


4
{6}
{6}
```